# How to do a overdue variable in a TODO List app in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm doing a TODO List in Laravel and in my dashboard i want to count how many overdue tasks the user have. I can count how many tasks are in total, how many tasks are to do, but i couldn't count how many overdue tasks the user have. I have the following in my dashboard:

[dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOG22.png)

And i have in my Manage tasks section the following:

[manage tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YLyy.png)

For the first image i have the next code in my `DashboardController.php` :

```
public function index()
{
        $currentTime = date('Y-m-d');
        $schedule    = Task::where('schedule');
        $overdue     = $currentTime > $schedule;

    $taskCount = Task::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get();
    $todoCount = Task::where('status',false)->get()->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id);
    $doneCount = Task::where('status',true)->get()->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id);
    
    
    $overdue = Task::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get();
    

    /////////SENDING TO THE DASHBOARD

    $doneTasks = Task::where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)->where('status',true)->paginate(3);
    $todoTasks = Task::where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)->where('status',false)->paginate(3);
    

    return view('user.dashboard',compact('taskCount','todoCount','doneCount','doneTasks','todoTasks'));
}
```

And in my `dashboard.blade.php` i have the following (summarizing only that part):

```
<p class="card-category">To do</p>
        <h3 class="card-title">{{$todoCount->count()}}

<p class="card-category">Done tasks</p>
              <h3 class="card-title">{{$doneCount->count()}}</h3>

<p class="card-category">Total tasks</p>
            <h3 class="card-title">{{$taskCount->count()}}</h3>
```

That is the way how i'm counting my tasks. But so far i can't count my overdue tasks, and sending to my `dashboard.blade.php` . In my database i have a **tasks** table and i have a field called **schedule** (with a date function). And for get the todo tasks (status is boolean), i have **status = 0** which means todo, and for done **status = 1** which means done.

As you can see for my second image, i have done, overdue and todo tasks. But in that table for my overdue tasks i have to do the following (in my `index.blade.php`):

```
@if ($task->status == 1)
 <span class="badge badge-success">Done</span>
  @elseif($task->status == 0 && $otherTime > $task->schedule)
     <span class="badge badge-danger">Overdue</span>
@else
<span class="badge badge-warning">To do</span>
@endif
```

For $otherTime i did the next:

```
$otherTime = date("Y-m-d");
```

So how could i do the count for my overdue tasks? Sorry if is to large, but i'm trying to specify with detail what i've done.

Thanks in advance

Comment: $task->schedule contain task date?  or how you store date for task->schedule

Comment: yes $task->schedule contain a task date, so if i create a task i can choose the date for that task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get count by query. In query compare date with today and you will get overdue tasks

// for records

```
$overdueTasks = Task::where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)
->where('date', '>', date('Y-m-d')) //compare date  // or ->where('date', '>=', '2019-11-08 23:59:59')  // or ->whereDate('date', '>', '2019-11-08')
->where('status',false)
->paginate(3);
```

// for counts

```
$overdueTaskCounts = Task::where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)
->where('date', '>', date('Y-m-d')) //compare date  // or ->where('date', '>=', '2019-11-08 23:59:59')  // or ->whereDate('date', '>', '2019-11-08')
->where('status',false)
->count();
```

Comment: Mmm but when i create a task i can choose when i should do it, for example if i create a task for tomorrow, and the next monday it should be Overdue, i couldn't do your answer because you are putting a specific date, and i want to compare my overdue task (with the date of that task) with today.

Comment: Chech now, use date() function

Comment: Nice now it works very good, just i change some things you do. Just as feedback i change ->where('date', '>', date('Y-m-d')) to ->where('schedule', '<', date('Y-m-d')). Because my schedule is my date for my task, and  to be overdue, my task with last date should be old than  date for NOW. But you helpme with your answer. Thanks so much